# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier because of special characters and foreign language names present in Account

Tags: visualforce, jquery, autocomplete

I have developed page with autoComplete feature. I'm getting an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error because of symbols used in Account Names such as  "诸城金盛-abc Commerce and" Co., Ltd. I'm posting my code for reference.

Visualforce page Code:

```
<apex:page id="pageId" standardController="Account"  lightningStylesheets="{!$User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4d'}" extensions="SFI_AccountExtension">
    <html lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <style>
            .ui-autocomplete {
            max-height: 100px;
            overflow-y: auto;

            overflow-x: hidden;
            }

            * html .ui-autocomplete {
            height: 100px;
            }


            td.data2Col {
            text-align: center !important;

            }
table {
border:0px;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0px;
}

td,th { 
padding:0px; 
border-width:0px; 
margin:0px; 

}

th{
width : 50px !important;
}

th{
width : 50px !important;
    padding-bottom: 20px;            
}
table#mytable tr td:first-child{display:none;}
table#mytable th{width:12%}            
table#mytable td{text-align:left;} 
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <apex:form id="formID">

            <apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" />
            <apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" />
            <center>
                <apex:pageblock mode="Edit" id="pageBLockID" >
                    <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection id="pageblockSectionID" title="Auto Complete Demo" columns="1" collapsible="false" >
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="mytable">
                            <tr id="tr1Id">
                                <apex:outputPanel >
                                    <th><apex:outputLabel value="Account" style="color: #4a4a56; font-weight: bold; font-size:91%;  text-align: left; "></apex:outputLabel></th>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="requiredInput"><div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                                            <apex:inputText label="Account " value="{!selectedAccount}"  id="AccountIds"    style="width : 206px;" />
                                        </div>    
                                    </td>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </apex:pageblockSection>

                </apex:pageblock>
            </center>
        </apex:form>
        <script>
        $( function() {
            var availableTags = {!accList};

            $('[id$=AccountIds]').autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        } );
        </script>



    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Code:

```
public class SFI_AccountExtension {
    public Account accountRecord {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List < String > accList {
        get;
        set;
    }
     public String  selectedAccount{
        get;
        set;
    }
    public SFI_AccountExtension(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
            selectedAccount = '';
            accountRecord = (Account) sc.getRecord();

        getAccountList();//method to load list of accounts


    }

    //Method to supply list of account with the record type name 'SAP Sold-To Customer' present in salesforce for auto complete
    public List < String > getAccountList() {
        accList = new List < String > ();
        Id RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Account'
                           AND Name = 'SAP Sold-To Customer'
                           limit 1
                          ].id;
        for (Account acc: [select name, SAP_Customer_Number__c from Account where recordTypeId =: RecordTypeId]) {
            accList.add('"' + acc.SAP_Customer_Number__c + ' - ' + acc.name + '"');
        }
        return accList;
    }

}
```

Can somebody please tell how to avoid this type of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to encode your data:

```
var availableTags = JSON.parse("{!JSENCODE(accList)}");
```

This may still result in errors, but it should be closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox when I'm trying to use this I'm getting this error " Error: Incorrect argument type for function 'JSENCODE()'. 
"

Comment: In that case, you might need to to JSON.serialize on the server side, then use the JSON string. You can't ordinarily have JavaScript variables with odd names, it's a limitation of JavaScript.